# How to install plugins on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I know there already are other questions like this, but I couldn't find anything useful.

I was trying to install ObjectAid on Eclipse 3.5.1.

I added it to the repository list, then checked ObjectAid UML Explorer. It said:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: ObjectAid Class Diagram 0.9.86 (com.objectaid.uml.feature.group 0.9.86)
  Missing requirement: ObjectAid Class Diagram 0.9.86 (com.objectaid.uml.feature.group 0.9.86) requires 'org.eclipse.draw2d 0.0.0'
```

I've had a look into /opt/eclipse/plugins and I've found org.eclipse.draw2d_3.5.2.v20091126-1908, but I couldn't figure out how to install it.

The operating system is Ubuntu.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: That it's in the plugins folder likely means that it IS installed.  Can you verify that Eclipse is finding the plugin via Help->About Eclipse->Installation Details->Plug-ins?  Make sure it is listed and check the version.  The Plug-in name should be "Graphical Editing Framework Draw2d".

Comment: thera are lot of plugins but no org.eclipse.draw2d, i dont understand.

Comment: If there is no plug-in with a plug-in id of "org.eclipse.draw2d", but there IS a corresponding directory (or .jar file) in your plugins directory, it's possible that the plug-in is failing to load.  Open the Error Log in Eclipse (Window->Show View->Error Log) and see if there are any errors listed where the plug-in is org.eclipse.draw2d.  Also ensure that the Eclipse instance you're running is in fact from /opt/eclipse/.

Comment: What's with the org.eclipse.draw2d version being "0.0.0"?  Maybe it can't find draw2d because there is no version 0.0.0!

Comment: Have you installed Eclipse from the repositories or from eclipse.org? Have you been able to install other plugins besides this one? I am asking because I ran into problems installing plugins with the Eclipse version from the Ubuntu repository.

Comment: From the repositories. Make sure you have installed also eclipse-pde (and maybe also eclipse-rpc, i dont remember exactly): have a look in System/administration/synaptic "eclipse".

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you didn't install the GEF, which is a requirement for ObjectAid. You can get it at http://www.eclipse.org/gef/.