# Eclipse: How to install a plugin manually?

Tags: java, eclipse

In one of my production environment, we have download restrictions so we have to download Eclipse plugin jar/zip file externally and then copy back to internal network and do the installation manually. Plugins to install are TestNG, C++ CDT etc.

Would appreciate step-by-step instructions to perform the above task and would this manually installation have the same outcome as if we do it from Eclipse install new software option like for example- automatically creating menu option for TestNG etc.?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install plugins on Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906152/how-to-install-plugins-on-eclipse)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can try this

click Help>Install New Software on the menu bar

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks that's the solution I desired. It is also quite neatly explained.

Comment: glad to hear that and help you.

Comment: I am trying to follow the above procedure to install maven-resources-plugin-3.1.0.jar downloaded from https://repo.maven.org/maven2, but it fails with "Could not find jar:file/C:/tmp/maven-resources-plugin-3.1.0.jar!". Installing directly from the Maven Repo fails because of firewall issues I have no control over.

Comment: How do you get marketplace plugins as standalone files on your computer?

Comment: I'm on a mac: help > install new software does not exist

Comment: [This answer](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/198699/) from the Eclipse forums may help those who encounter the "Could not find jar:file" error that @bobmcn mentioned above. I'm pretty sure this only applies to plugin developers though.

Comment: For the problem "Could not find jar:file" (for me experienced unfortunately on Windows) try to fix the path and change `jar:file:/C:/....` into `jar:file://C:/....` (one `/` is missing after `file:`)

Answer (score 15):

1. Download your plugin
2. Open Eclipse
3. From the menu choose: `Help` / `Install New Software...`
4. Click the `Add` button
5. In the `Add Repository` dialog that appears, click the `Archive` button next to the `Location` field
6. Select your plugin file, click `OK`

You could also just copy plugins to the `eclipse/plugins` directory, but it's [not recommended](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_install_new_plug-ins%3F).

Comment: Thanks this is also the correct answer. But the other answer used  pictorial sequence with text to nail it. Appreciate your effort for the prompt response!