# How to configure jboss application server with eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

I did the following steps.

To enable Eclipse to manage JBoss Application Server, you need to install the JBoss AS tools in Eclipse:

Start an instance of Eclipse.
Click Window > Preferences.
Expand the Server list, and click Runtime Environments.
In the Server Runtime Environments view, click Add.
In the New Server Runtime Environment dialog, click Download additional server adapters.
In the Install New Extension dialog, wait until the alphabetic list of server adapters is populated, then scroll down the list, and locate JBossAS Tools.
Click on this entry to select it, and click Next.
In the Review Licenses view, accept the license agreement, and click Finish.
Click OK to accept the restart warning.
The server adapter download is initiated, which may take a few moments. If you are presented with a security warning about unsigned content, ignore it by clicking OK. Once the server adapter is installed, click OK to restart Eclipse.

But still i'm getting this error while adding JbossAS tool

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: JBossAS Tools 3.0.3.Final-v20150325-0035-B129 (org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.feature.feature.group 3.0.3.Final-v20150325-0035-B129)
  Missing requirement: JBossAS Tools Server / JMX Integration 3.0.3.Final-v20150325-0035-B129 (org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.jmx.integration.feature.feature.group 3.0.3.Final-v20150325-0035-B129) requires 'org.eclipse.rse.core 3.1.200' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: JBossAS Tools 3.0.3.Final-v20150325-0035-B129 (org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.feature.feature.group 3.0.3.Final-v20150325-0035-B129)
    To: org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.jmx.integration.feature.feature.group [3.0.3.Final-v20150325-0035-B129]

can anyone help me on this? i'm newbie to java world. using  Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need **org.eclipse.rse.core 3.1.200**:

> *Software being installed*: JBossAS Tools 3.0.3.Final-v20150325-0035-B129 (org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.feature.feature.group
>   3.0.3.Final-v20150325-0035-B129)
>
> *Missing requirement*: JBossAS Tools Server / JMX Integration 3.0.3.Final-v20150325-0035-B129 (org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.jmx.integration.feature.feature.group
>   3.0.3.Final-v20150325-0035-B129) **requires 'org.eclipse.rse.core 3.1.200'** but it could not be found Cannot satisfy dependency

I had a similar error where I was missing a TM Terminal dependency. I downloaded the latest jbosstoolstarget zip from [JBoss Tools](http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/static/targetplatforms/jbosstoolstarget/) and installed the dependency from there. Looks like you can do the same in your case. Install the RSE dependency from the jbosstoolstarget zip using Eclipse.

[This stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31553376/eclipse-how-to-install-a-plugin-manually) explains how to manually install software from a zip using Eclipse.

Once that dependency is installed, you should be able to install and configure JBoss Tools for JBoss application servers in Eclipse.