# No direct classpath access for installation

Tags: eclipse, gradle, installation, classpath

As part of corporate security measures all personal systems have access to the classpath, environment variables, etc. locked down to anyone other than those with admin rights. Is there a way to install something like Gradle into Eclipse when access to the Marketplace, "set..." in a command prompt or PowerShell is unavailable? I don't think just working with Eclipse's build path would do the trick. Any thoughts?

Thank you, Dave.

Comment: Whats preventing you from manually installing the Gradle plugin into Eclipse? ( Don't think class path would have an impact because that is specific to finding java Classes for loading)

Comment: Normally, I'd just go to the Eclipse Marketplace and install new plugins with little trouble. Here, I have no access to the Marketplace. As a work-around I downloaded the Gradle-4.7.zip and tried to add it to the repository manually- as a *.zip, individual jars, and off of bin, but this doesn't seem the right option, as messages like "No software site found" are thrown. Copying/pasting the unzipped Gradle jars into Eclipse doesn't sound right either, as such a manual process would seem to risk unintended errors should something be missed or improperly placed.

Comment: could you do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31553376/eclipse-how-to-install-a-plugin-manually      ...................   and install Buildship (eclipse gradle plugin)