# How to add plugin manually to existing eclipse project?

Tags: java, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I have created a plugin project and exported it as a plugin and i want to add it to another existing RCP project. So is there any steps to add plugin manually to existing project.

Comment: Add the plug-in to the target platform (_Window > Preferences: Plug-in Development > Target Platform_) to be able to depend on it or to add it in a feature. Or if you want to install the plug-in into an Eclipse-based application, copy the JAR into the `dropins` folder.

Comment: possible dublicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31553376/eclipse-how-to-install-a-plugin-manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the below step to achieve the goal:

1. In Eclipse, go to Help > Install New Software.
2. Press the Add button. This displays the Add Repository window.
3. In the Add Repository window, press the Archive button to open a file browser.
4. In the file browser, select your Eclipse plugin file that you created. Click Open to return to the previous dialog.
5. The Add Repository window appears. Press OK.
6. The installation details are displayed. Press Next. The items you checked are listed. Press Next again.
7. Accept the terms of the license agreement and click Finish.
8. Check the Java ME SDK Tools Category and its subcategories and press the Next button to start the Add wizard.
9. Accept the terms of the license agreement and click Finish. The installation process starts.
10. When the installation process completes, restart Eclipse.