# IntelliJ sbt unresolved dependencies

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt, intellij-plugin

i have a scala sbt project imported in the IntelliJ 2019.1. Operate on the two independent computers:
- computer 1 with typical internet connection - let's call it **"normal"**,
- computer 2 without internet connection - name it **"blind"**.

On the 'normal' and 'blind' computer both IntelliJ and scala plugin with the same versions are being installed. When operating on 'normal' computer everything goes well - am able to compile, clean, assembly code from the IntelliJ sbt shell. When operating on 'blind' computer, I am not capable of build the project - get unresolved dependencies error in the sbt console.  I have already moved the dependencies from `~/.sbt`, `~/.ivy2`, `~/.m2` directories from 'normal' to 'blind' computer also.

**Error message:**

```
[info] Loading settings from idea.sbt ... 
[info] Loading global plugin from /home/myuser/.sbt/1.0/plugins
[info] Updating {file:/home/tomaszk/.sbt/1.0/plugins/}global-plugins...
[warn] :: UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES ::
[warn] :: io.github.sugakandrey#scala-compiler-indices-protocol_2.12;0.1.1: Resolution failed several times for dependency: io.github.sugakandrey#scala-compiler-indices-protocol_2.12;0.1.1 {compile=[default(compile)]}
...
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: io.github.sugakandrey#scala-compiler-indices-protocol_2.12...
```

**build.properties**

```
sbt.version=1.0.3
```

**build.sbt**

```
name := "my_proj"
version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.5"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.6.3" % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.10" % "1.6.3" % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.10.1"
libraryDependencies += "com.databricks" % "spark-csv_2.10" % "1.5.0"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.1"
assemblyOption in assembly := (assemblyOption in assembly).value.copy(includeScala = false)
assemblyJarName in assembly := "my_proj.jar"
```

Shall i change the sbt version maybe or move another directories which sore some dependencies or the problem is related to the other issue?

This topis is a bit related to my previous question: [Use Scala on computer without internet connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56545756/use-scala-on-computer-without-internet-connection)

- TK

Comment: sbt 1.0 uses Scala 2.12 for build definitions and plugins, but you are using Scala 2.10. Maybe try downgrading sbt version or upgrading scala version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MarioGalic sugested, the problem was with the scala and sbt versions - had to downgrade the IntelliJ Scala Plugin from 2019.1.9 to 2019.1.3 to solve the issue.

Comment: I didn't test it on the version 2019.2 - no idea about this version of Idea. :)

Comment: I am using Intellij 2020.3 and facing the same problem