# How to make Feature plugins or extensions in Eclipse 4.16 .Kindly help me

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse

[image: Eclipse 4.16 Plugin Issue Image]

How to install plugin/extension archive to Eclipse 4.16? I am unable to manually extend the functionality of Eclipse by adding an archive to Eclipse paths.I referred this URL: [Eclipse: How to install a plugin manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31553376/eclipse-how-to-install-a-plugin-manually)

Comment: Are you sure that's an Update Site and not an entire installation?

Comment: yes , you are correct it is an eclipse bundle ......Can you share the STS install site for 3.9.8 along with JBoss Tools Site for Java 8

Comment: Everything can be found here: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/ (in the Eclipse IDE _Help > Eclipse Marketplace_).