# How to downgrade checkstyle to 8.40 or 8.41 in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, checkstyle

I am kind of struggling to downgrade checkstyle plugin in Eclipse. The desired version is 8.40 or 8.41. I downloaded .zip/.jar from:

https://github.com/checkstyle/eclipse-cs/releases

and I followed the instructions from:

[Eclipse: How to install a plugin manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31553376/eclipse-how-to-install-a-plugin-manually)

Trying to install I get:

`Could not find jar:file:/C:/Users/xxx/Downloads/checkstyle-8.40-all.jar`

Comment: That download does not appear to be an Eclipse plug-in, so you can't just install it.

Comment: Ok. Any idea how to do so? I can't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. *Help*
2. *Install New Software...*
3. Uncheck *Show only the latest versions of available software*
4. In *Work with* paste https://checkstyle.org/eclipse-cs-update-site/ and you'll get a list of available versions

Comment: For older versions? Sorry, I am new to Eclipse.

Comment: No, sorry, only for the latest version. Comment deleted, answer upvoted.